# How to shutdown the computer when a USB is attached?

Tags: windows, usb, shutdown

I want to perform one security mechanism, but I don't know whether it is possible.

I want to Shutdown/Turn Off PC/System when any USB device attach to it.

Comment: What version of Windows ?

Comment: @Lawrence -It's Windows 7 and 8 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you know what your doing, shutting down a computer when any USB device attaches to it could put you in a hard spot when you try to connect your Keyboard for example.

With that disclaimer out of the way, Windows Scheduler would be the easiest way to accomplish this.  Write a little batch script that shuts down the computer:

```
@echo off
shutdown \p
```

And set a scheduled task using Windows Scheduler to run that batch script every time a USB device is inserted.  And your done!